# I created Recyclerview inside the Bottom Sheet Layout , How can i implement Onclicklistener method for that?

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener, android-bottomsheetdialog

I passed the context as 'Suggestion_Adapter.Onitemclicklistenersuggestion) getContext()'  I got an error how can I solve this? I submitted the bottom sheet class and adapter class below, Thank you
Which Context I want to pass inside the Onclicklistener method in the bottom sheet

`suggestion_adapter.setOnitemclicklistener((**context**);`

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Bottomsheet extends BottomSheetDialogFragment implements Suggestion_Adapter.Onitemclicklistenersuggestion{    

    DatabaseReference databaseReference2;
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewsuggestion;
    private Suggestion_Adapter suggestion_adapter;
    private List<Model_upload> suggestion_uploads;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_layout,container,false);



        databaseReference2= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Product_Details");

        recyclerViewsuggestion=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerviewsuggestionid);
        recyclerViewsuggestion.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);


        recyclerViewsuggestion.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        suggestion_uploads=new ArrayList<>();

        databaseReference2.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                suggestion_uploads.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                {
                    Model_upload mp=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model_upload.class);

                    if(mp.getSize().equals("S"))
                    {
                        Model_upload md=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model_upload.class);
                    //    md.setMkey(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                        suggestion_uploads.add(md);
                    }
                    else if(mp.getSize().equals("M"))
                    {
                        Model_upload md=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model_upload.class);
                        //    md.setMkey(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                        suggestion_uploads.add(md);
                    }
                    else if(mp.getSize().equals("L"))
                    {
                        Model_upload md=dataSnapshot1.getValue(Model_upload.class);
                        //    md.setMkey(dataSnapshot1.getKey());
                        suggestion_uploads.add(md);
                    }

                }

                suggestion_adapter=new Suggestion_Adapter(getContext(),suggestion_uploads);
                recyclerViewsuggestion.setAdapter(suggestion_adapter);

                suggestion_adapter.setOnitemclicklistener((Suggestion_Adapter.Onitemclicklistenersuggestion) getContext());

                suggestion_adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void clicktoupdate(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

> My Adapter class -> SuggestionAdapter

```
package com.app.futurelistuser.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.app.futurelistuser.Model.Model_upload;
import com.app.futurelistuser.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class Suggestion_Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Suggestion_Adapter.Suggestion_viewholder> {
    private Context mcontext;
    private List<Model_upload> mlist;
    private Onitemclicklistenersuggestion listener;

    public Suggestion_Adapter(Context mcontext, List<Model_upload> mlist) {
        this.mcontext = mcontext;
        this.mlist = mlist;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Suggestion_viewholder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view= LayoutInflater.from(mcontext).inflate(R.layout.suggesstion_card_view,parent,false);

        return new Suggestion_viewholder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull Suggestion_viewholder holder, int position) {

        Model_upload mu=mlist.get(position);


        holder.tvname.setText(""+mu.getCloth_name());
     //   holder.tvprice.setText(""+mu.getPrice());


        Picasso.get()
                .load(mu.getImg_link())
                .centerCrop()
                .fit()
                .into(holder.iv);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mlist.size();
    }

    public class Suggestion_viewholder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        private ImageView iv;
        private TextView tvname,tvprice;

        public Suggestion_viewholder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            iv=itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            tvname=itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameid);
            tvprice=itemView.findViewById(R.id.priceid);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);



        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if(listener!=null)
            {
                int position=getAdapterPosition();
                if(position!=RecyclerView.NO_POSITION)
                {
                    listener.clicktoupdate(position);
                }

            }
        }
    }
    public interface Onitemclicklistenersuggestion
    {
        void clicktoupdate(int poistion);

    }

    public void setOnitemclicklistener(Onitemclicklistenersuggestion mlistener)
    {
        listener=mlistener;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing the context, do this

```
suggestion_adapter.setOnitemclicklistener(new Suggestion_Adapter.Onitemclicklistenersuggestion(){
        @Override
        public void clicktoupdate(int poistion); {
            //handle click event
        }
    });
```

Comment: **This is working Perfectly. Thank you So much for your help**